How to properly center the "Y" inside this svg vertically and horizontally?
I have this svg which is basically a "Y" inside of a polygon, but I can't manage to center the "Y" inside of the polygon vertically and horizontally, here's the svg:


        <svg id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" fill="none">
            <title>Loader Logo</title>
            <g>
                <g id="Y" transform="translate(11.000000, 5.000000)">
                    <path
                          d="m 35,37.018555 c 3.686193,8.066969 7.372385,16.133937 11.058578,24.200905 0,6.557364 0,13.114728 0,19.672093 2.577904,0.07335 5.155807,0.146697 7.733711,0.220046 0,-6.753756 0,-13.507511 0,-20.261265 4.224292,-8.815029 8.450947,-17.628029 12.673514,-26.444539 -2.882118,-0.08201 -5.764235,-0.16401 -8.646353,-0.246014 -2.621719,5.556806 -5.242844,11.114115 -7.86433,16.671119 -2.596764,-5.705351 -5.191816,-11.412041 -7.78969,-17.116521 -2.929616,-0.08336 -5.859232,-0.166714 -8.788847,-0.250069 0.541139,1.184749 1.082278,2.369497 1.623417,3.554245 z"
                          fill="#64ffda"/>
                </g>
                <path id="outline"
                    stroke="#64ffda"
                    strokeWidth="5"
                    strokeLinecap="round"
                    strokeLinejoin="round"
            fill="none"
                    d="M 50, 5
                  L 11, 27
                  L 11, 72
                  L 50, 95
                  L 89, 73
                  L 89, 28 z"
                />
            </g>
        </svg>



I tried everything from using CSS to trying to draw another svg with Y centered but it doesn't work

Replace the transform of the #Y with transform="translate(0,-5)"

@enxaneta that works, thank you!

Keep in mind you can solve these problems way faster and better using a graphic editor like inkscape (free), Illustrator etc.  Complex SVG vector graphics are usually designed with aforementioned editors and not "coded from scratch" – albeit optimized to get rid of editors code overhead.

The reason is that you used wrong transform. I updated your svg code and it works as you want.


<svg id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" fill="none">
    <title>Loader Logo</title>
    <g>
        <g id="Y" transform="translate(0, -5)">
            <path d="m 35,37.018555 c 3.686193,8.066969 7.372385,16.133937 11.058578,24.200905 0,6.557364 0,13.114728 0,19.672093 2.577904,0.07335 5.155807,0.146697 7.733711,0.220046 0,-6.753756 0,-13.507511 0,-20.261265 4.224292,-8.815029 8.450947,-17.628029 12.673514,-26.444539 -2.882118,-0.08201 -5.764235,-0.16401 -8.646353,-0.246014 -2.621719,5.556806 -5.242844,11.114115 -7.86433,16.671119 -2.596764,-5.705351 -5.191816,-11.412041 -7.78969,-17.116521 -2.929616,-0.08336 -5.859232,-0.166714 -8.788847,-0.250069 0.541139,1.184749 1.082278,2.369497 1.623417,3.554245 z"
                          fill="#64ffda"/>
        </g>
        <path id="outline"
            stroke="#64ffda"
            strokeWidth="5"
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
            fill="none"
            d="M 50, 5
               L 11, 27
               L 11, 72
               L 50, 95
               L 89, 73
               L 89, 28 z"
            />
    </g>
</svg>




This did infact center horizontally but for vertical centering, I had to add translate(0,-5)

Hi, @Dorian, yes, you can. If it's translate(0, -6.5), it will be more correct.

So my answer is helpful for you?

yes, just change translate(0, 0) to translate(0, -5) so I can accept it as the answer

I already updated my answer. If it helps you, please check What should I do when someone answers my question?

Note: most of your SVG attributes are wrong, SVG attributes are not CamelCased
For dynamically positioning anything:
You can position elements exactly by animating them over a path
Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mpath


<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="height:180px">
  <path id="Y" visibility="hidden" fill="#64ffda" d="M-15 -20c3.7 8.1 7.4 16.1 11.1 24.2 0 6.6 0 13.1 0 19.7 2.6.1 5.2.1 7.7.2 0-6.8 0-13.5 0-20.3 4.2-8.8 8.5-17.6 12.7-26.4-2.9-.1-5.8-.2-8.6-.2-2.6 5.6-5.2 11.1-7.9 16.7-2.6-5.7-5.2-11.4-7.8-17.1-2.9-.1-5.9-.2-8.8-.3.5 1.2 1.1 2.4 1.6 3.6z">
    <set attributeName="visibility" from="hidden" to="visible" begin="0s" />
    <animateMotion keyPoints="0;.5" dur="1s" fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear">
      <mpath href="#track" />
    </animateMotion>
  </path>
  <path stroke="#64ffda" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" d="M50 5L11 27L11 72L50 95L89 73L89 28z"/>
  <circle cx="89" cy="28" fill="red" r="4" />
  <circle cx="11" cy="72" fill="green" r="4"/>
  <path id="track" d="M89 28L11 72" stroke="blue" Xvisibility="hidden"></path>
</svg>




I reduced your Y path precision in: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/#)

SVG does not know what the center of your Y is

Position the Y over the red circle by adjusting the M-15 -20 values.
Effectively the same as applying a transform="translate(x,y)")
set animateMotion keyPoints="0;.001" to "disable" the move


visibility="hidden" is required to prevent a FOUC (Flash of unstyled content)

keyPoints="0;.5" sets it to halfway on the #track mpath at the end of the animation

set dur="1s" to dur="0.001s" for "instant display"

set the #track stroke to visibility="hidden"

remove the guide circles

done



SVG attributes are not CamelCased - sorry, but you know that this is not true per se: viewBox, pathLength, keyPoints, keyTimes, calcMode definitely require CamelCase notation. Also, the motion path example does not solve the automatic centreing/alignment problem - you still need to adjust the M coordinates - the mpath (...why isn't it camel case btw? =) does not really add any new "automatic" alignment capabilities.
